# EntityManager refresh

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, entitymanager

I reverse engineered some db tables, and a facade interface and implementing class were made.
I need to do a refresh() on an entity, but the EntityManager is private from the reverse engineering, and I do not want to edit a reverse engineerined class.
How do I go about getting the EntityManger so I may call refresh()?

Answer (score 1):

If private is your only barrier and you have no other reasonable solution, try using reflection?

```
Field entityManagerField = reverseEngineeredInstance.class.getField("entityManager");
entityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerField.get(reverseEngineeredInstance);
```

And there you have your EntityManager. Naturally, I would not recommend using reflection in production code, but if it's that or nothing, then go ahead.